# RewriteRule redirect not including parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to do is redirect

http://example.com/sample/

to

http://example.com/this/that/?which=those

This is what I have tried;

```
RewriteRule ^sample.*$ http://example.com/this/that/?which=those [R=301,L]
```

But it redirects to http://example.com/this/that/ , without the parameter.

Only when I write something (random) after the url, it redirects correctly, including the parameter.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^sample/?$ /this/that/?which=those [R=302,L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache and restart your browser once before testing this.

**IMPORTANT:** Remember to not to use `R=301 (Permanent Redirect)` while testing mod_rewrite rules. ONLY after you verify it to be working, change `R=302 (Temporary Redirect)` to `R=301 (Permanent Redirect)`

Comment: Just after I posted this, I emptied the cache what solved the problem. It worked, but I was still rewriting [code](sample) to 'sample/' to 'this/that/?which=those'. Thank you for showing me correct way to do this, also with the correct Flags to use. You the man and definitely marked as the answer!! +1

Comment: One question though, why do I have to use the full URL (http://example.com/) when rewriting/redirecting? Without it doesn't work... thanks!!

Comment: As I showed in my example above that you don't need to use domain name in redirect URL.

Comment: Well, if I don't use it, the redirect includes my website structure (home/example/public_html/)...

Comment: And I think you made a mistake: shouldn't '/this/that/?which=those' be without the first slash -> 'this/that/?which=those'? Cheers

Comment: Depending on situations first slash may or may not be needed. If it works for your Apache with leading slash, feel free to omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^sample(.*)? http://example.com/this/that/?which=those [R=301,L]
```

Here, we are making the wildcard optional by capturing it and using the optional regex flag: `(.*)?`

So, both `sample` and `sample/test/hello`, will redirect.